# Which statistical test should be used for comparing frequencies of a categorical variable levels by another categorical variable (figure provided)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-data, differences

I would like to show that marital statuses differ between different educational levels. Which statistical test should be used for this purpose?

**And how should I write it under my methods?**

METHODS: Proportional comparisons were done using test X?

RESULTS: The proportions of marital status levels differed between the educational levels (p-value of test X).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you in addition to the plot include a table of the counts, as an edit to the post? so we can use in answering? And, do you have some specific hypothesis in mind? Age could be a factor ... PhD's could have a different age distribution than Middle School's --- Any information on that?

Comment: Thanks! You are digging too deep, meaning that my question is much simpler. I'm interested in a crude analysis only. Is there a p-value-way for saying that the distributions of marital status differ for people with different educational level?

Comment: Use a chi-square test then

Comment: It seems to me that a good figure will say it all.  The numbers suggest you stratified your sample by marriage status, though, so it would be clearer (and more consistent with the sampling strategy) to stratify the figure by status, too, rather than educational attainment; and it could help to make the total lengths of the bars proportional to stratum size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a chi-square test.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test

The chi-square test compares the "observed" frequencies in each cell with the "expected" frequencies that you would have gotten if there were no relationship whatsoever between the two variables. A significant p value indicates that you can reject the null hypotheses of no relationship at the given significance level, although note that the test does not tell you WHICH categories are significantly different from each other, just that there is a significant difference somewhere in the table.

To report the result of your test you probably want to indicate the value of the chi-Square test itself, the degrees of freedom for the table, which in your case is 12, because the formula is: ​(number of rows-1)*(number of columns-1), and the resulting p value. One warning: Chi-Square tests can be "unstable" (give strange answers) when there are "small" numbers of observations (say <5) in particular cells. You have some cells with only 4 observations in them here, so you might want to first combine widowed and divorced, re-do the table, and run the test again, if you want to be sure.

Comment: There's no need to combine cells and it's ok to ignore the warnings: the p-value will be more than accurate enough.  It you're truly worried about that, use Fisher's Exact test, which would be appropriate assuming the data collection was stratified by marriage status.  BTW, since all counts are multiples of 3 I suspect these are artificial data constructed for a textbook problem.

Comment: The main problem is with low expected frequencies. Low observed frequencies are not really an issue.

Comment: Good answer, thank you! One final thing, should I refer to it as Pearson's chi-squared test or just Chi-squared test?

Comment: In the circles I run in (political science and social psychology) we just say "chi-squared" without "Pearson's" but others might disagree.